# MassTransit and EventHub consumer groups

Tags: masstransit, azure-eventhub

In c#, how do we register MassTransit consumers tied to an Azure EventHub consumer group?

I see in the documentation "The consumer group specified must be unique to the application, and shared..." in the documentation website here https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/azure-event-hub

There appears to be no other reference to consumer groups in any documentation on the site related to EventHub. I've found no examples online, questions asked online, etc. I've also looked through the available intellisense for the MassTransit.EventHub package and no dice there either.

Thanks to anyone who has an idea about this!

Is this implemented?

Comment: After looking through MT source code, I believe I found an overload of ReceiveEndpoint which also takes a consumer group name. Something else is preventing me from validating this actually works because the consumer isn't getting any messages. The raw Microsoft library consumer I made will consume but MassTransit has some other settings I haven't found yet I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The overload I referenced in the comment works.